# Issue in the deployment of a lambda using Cloudformation

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless

I deployed my lambda function using cloudformation like this.

```
aws cloudformation package \
  --template-file template.yaml \
  --output-template-file serverless-output.yaml \
  --s3-bucket <bucket-name>
aws cloudformation deploy \
  --template-file serverless-output.yaml \
  --stack-name prod \
  --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
```

But the server does not work and gives `Internal Server Error`.
So I tried to deploy the lambda using `sls deploy` command and it does work fine for me.
I am not sure why it is.
Do you have some suggestion?
I hope your kind response.
Thank you.

Comment: By "the server" do you mean API Gateway/Lambda?  Is there a log for the lambda function, can you provide some of that?  Is the lambda function configured correctly when you use the cloudformation method?  (e.g. runtime, vpc, etc)?

Comment: My template.yml file is like this.
```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Resources:
  GraphQL:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: stack7
      Handler: src/index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      Events:
        AnyRequest:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /graphql
            Method: ANY
```

Comment: Please add new code by updating the question, not in comments. It difficult to read without any formating.

Comment: Yes, I created a question in this link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66692348/does-not-the-server-deployed-using-cloudformation-work