# Does not the server deployed using Cloudformation work

Tags: lambda, graphql, aws-cloudformation

I am running a graphql server.
The serer does work fine for me when I deployed using Serverless, but it doesn't work when I deployed with cloudformation.
Here is my template.yml.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Resources:
  GraphQL:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: src/index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      Events:
        AnyRequest:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /graphql
            Method: ANY
```

Please give me a suggestion.

Comment: "does work fine" is not specific. What exactly is happening? Any error messages?

Comment: It gives me the "internal server error" message when I run query.